# jquery scrollTo to work with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting a simple jquery code to work. I want a button to scroll the page down to another div.

The code is in here: http://jsfiddle.net/utm6d/

html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Scroll down!</h1>
      <a  type="button" id="helloclick" class="btn btn-default">scroll!</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container text-center" id="second">
    <p> come here </p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#helloclick').click(function(){
   $('html, body').ScrollTo("#second");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#helloclick').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#second').offset().top
}, 500);});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/utm6d/1/)**

Comment: hmm.. that doesn't do anything for me ?!

Comment: @Kiarash:have you checked the fiddle. also make sure that scroll appears in output tab to see the changes.

Comment: yes, I have the fiddle open. and I see the scroll button.. but no scrolling.

Comment: @Kiarash:resize the window till scroll appears on page. and then click on button.

Comment: i see. The scroll wasn't showing.  but how can I force it to go to the new section. even without scroll?

Comment: @Kiarash: That is not possible...how can you go to new section if scroll doesnt appear??

Comment: I mean, if the user's screen is too big, the scroll will not automatically be there. I still want the new section to be the top of the page. There should be a way...

Comment: @Kiarash: increase the top position for the div then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `scrollTop()` method with an `offset()` of your target object.

```
$(function() {
    $('#helloclick').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

EDIT: Code needed to be wrapped in `$(function() {...});`, to ensure `#helloclick` & `#second` are loaded before being executed.

**See it working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r9zD/)**

Comment: my screen is not changing at all after clicking on the button

Comment: the top of the window is supposed to go to "come here", right?

Comment: You should not be omitting the href attribute, you should add `href="#"`  to `#helloclick`

Comment: no error. (except event.returnValue is deprecated. warning)

Comment: nevermind. My screen is too big. but how can I force the button to move the page, even if the window is too big?

Comment: Yes it does, but, there's not enough height to enable the scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/2r9zD/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not have `.ScrollTo()` method.

In your case, you need to use **[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)**:

```
$('#helloclick').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#second').offset().top });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/utm6d/3/)**